# How to replace a word in WooCommerce order email template?

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

So I need to replace the word "Order" with "Submission" in customer processing order email in woocommerce.

I was able to change the word in the first two places but unable to find a way to change it in one place(where it says: [Order #1044]

[image]

Is it possible to change?

Comment: yes you can write your own email templates. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automated-follow-up-emails-docs/custom-email-templates/

Comment: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.1.0/templates/emails/email-order-details.php#L34 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php.

Comment: @7uc1f3r thank you. Changed it in line #34. Should I delete this question?

Comment: I need to ask one more thing. To prevent the changes from being erased when the woocommerce plugin is updated in near future, is there any solution? I tried creating the directory in the child-theme folder[themes/child-theme/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-details.php] but when I place the file here, the changes won't reflect in the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This can be adjusted 
>   by editing https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.1.0/templates/emails/email-order-details.php
>
> - This template can be overridden by copying it to **`yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php`**.

Line nr [34](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.1.0/templates/emails/email-order-details.php#L34)

The correct path is: **`yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php`**

NOT

yourtheme/woocommerce/**templates**/emails/email-order-details.php

> Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme
>   https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Regarding the path, I need to understand why are we excluding the templates from the path? Just for my knowledge purpose(of course if it's not too much to ask)

Comment: Also, I just tried with the updated path but the incoming mails are still showing the word "Order"  that we replaced in the files(in child theme).

Comment: I think this setting was removed. But let me check this answer.

Comment: or this https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I don't know what is the issue.

Comment: Difficult to tell without getting a closer look. Unfortunately, I can only refer you to topics that have a related problem.

Comment: That's ok. At least I learned something. Wish it could be solved though. Thank you.